# Gram-Schmidt process animation confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

I was looking for a geometrical explanation for the Gram-Schmidt process and came across this animation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process):

[image: The animation]

In the description, the owner wrote that he found an intermediate vector $v'_3$ by subtracting from $v_3$ its projection onto $u_1$. Then, $u_3$ is obtained by subtracting from $v'_3$ its projection onto $u_2$.

But given the formula $u_3=v_3-\operatorname{proj}_{u_1}(v_3)-\operatorname{proj}_{u_2}(v_3)$, does the description imply that $\operatorname{proj}_{u_2}(v_3)$ is the same as $proj_{u_2}(v'_3)$?

Edit: Also, why is vector $u_3$ ,which is a combination of vector $v'_3$ and a vector on $u_2$, still orthogonal to $u_1$? thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Note in particular that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{proj}
\proj_{u_2}(v_3')=\proj_{u_2}(v_3-\proj_{u_1}(v_3)) =
\\
\proj_{u_2}(v_3)- \proj_{u_2}(\proj_{u_1}(v_3))
$$
Now, can you see why the second term above should be zero?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same because $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal by construction.

Recall that projection maps are linear. Hence
$$\text{proj}_{u_2}(v_3')=\text{proj}_{u_2}(v_3-\text{proj}_{u_1}(v_3))
= \text{proj}_{u_2}(v_3) - \text{proj}_{u_2}[\text{proj}_{u_1}(v_3)].$$

Orthogonality of $u_1$ and $u_2$ ensures that $\text{proj}_{u_2}[\text{proj}_{u_1}(v)] = 0 $ for all $v$, leaving us with
$$\text{proj}_{u_2}(v_3')=\text{proj}_{u_2}(v_3).$$

Note that this same argument works when performing the Gram-Schmidt process in 4 or more dimensions.